# how to write and include bibliography in Latex from Mendeley (step by step)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I have started using Latex for a few days, so I'm a beginner. However, I succeeded to set and customize everything I need for my book writing..except for the bibliography. I am very confused about the several ways in which the bibliography can be written and include in a Latex document.

I'm using TexShop on a Mac to write my main file which includes several chapters.
I'm trying to use the package natbib and I have a .bib file resulting from the exportation of my bibliography from Mendeley.
my file is like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,  twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[a4paper,top=3.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\usepackage{topfront}

\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{natbib}


\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\input{capitoli/Results1.tex}
\end{document}
```

and my results1.tex file is:

```
\begin{document}
\chapter{Results part I}
orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit\cite{Author2015a}
\bibliography{library}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

and, finally, my .bib file (one example entry) which is in the same directory of the others

```
@article{Author2015a,
author = {Author, Elizabeth C},
doi = {10.1016/j.apgeog.2014.12.002},
file = {:Users/Giovanna/Documents/phd/letteratura phd/author 2015           Five decades of neighborhood classifications and their transitions.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0143-6228},
journal = {Applied Geography},
pages = {1--11},
publisher = {Elsevier Ltd},
title = {{Five decades of neighborhood classi fi cations and their transitions : A comparison of four US cities , 1970 e 2010}},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apgeog.2014.12.002},
volume = {57},
year = {2015}
},
```

However, what i get in my final pfd is a "?" instead of the reference.
Where is the problem?
Now I downloaded also Bibdesk in trying to solve the problem but I cannot understand how.
I know that probably is a basic question but I really cannot fix it (even after having read several article and tutorial about that.
Thank you

Comment: Remove `\printbibliography`. This is not a bibtex command, but from the `biblatex` package.

Comment: @ggg Also don't use `\bibliography{library.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` two times. Remove it from your preamble and leave it only where you want to have your bibliography.

Comment: @ggg This was the instance of `\bibliography{library.bib} \bibliographystyle{plainnat}` which was OK, remove the the one before `\begin{document}`. Also the second `\begin{document}` in `results1.tex` looks wrong.

Comment: @samcarter got it (hope so) for the \bibliography{library.bib}. what is wrong with the second \begin{document} in results1.tex ? there is not \end{document} because it is inlcude in the main file (the fiirst one i wrote)

Comment: @ggg one document typically only has one `\begin{document}` in the main file, not in the sub files. There is also a `]` missing before `{geometry}`

Comment: @ggg And `\bibliography{library.bib}` should be `\bibliography{library}`

Comment: @ggg I fixed a couple of errors, can you try if you can compile the code from my "answer" below?

Comment: @ggg The `]` is missing before `{geometry}`, not after

Comment: @ggg The error message you show indicates that you did not remove the .bib ending in `\bibliography{library}`

Comment: If you can choose, use biblatex and biber -> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: @Johannes_B i will have a look at that combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of several problems:

- `\bibliography{library}` should be called without file extension -> remove the `.bib`
- `\bibliography{library}
  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}` are only to be used once at the location where the location where the bibliography should be inserted.
- the closing `]` is missing in `\usepackage[a4paper,top=3.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}`
- `\begin{document}` must be written only once, at the start of the document and not in the included files (there are exceptions, but they don't apply here)
- compilation should be (pdf)latex, bibtex, (pdf)latex, (pdf)latex and it is important to check that the document compiles without errors, which some of the problems above surly caused.

---

Minimal working example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,  twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\usepackage{topfront}
%
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents} % <- Just for the MWE, in real live have a seperate .bib file
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}% <- Just for the MWE, in real live have a seperate .bib file
@article{Author2015a,
author = {Author, Elizabeth C},
doi = {10.1016/j.apgeog.2014.12.002},
file = {:Users/Giovanna/Documents/phd/letteratura phd/author 2015           Five decades of neighborhood classifications and their transitions.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0143-6228},
journal = {Applied Geography},
pages = {1--11},
publisher = {Elsevier Ltd},
title = {{Five decades of neighborhood classi fi cations and their transitions : A comparison of four US cities , 1970 e 2010}},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apgeog.2014.12.002},
volume = {57},
year = {2015}
},
\end{filecontents*}% <- Just for the MWE, in real live have a seperate .bib file


\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Results part I}
orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit\cite{Author2015a}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: yes it perfectly works. Are you suggesting that the problem, and so the solution, is in the .bib file?

Comment: @ggg The bib file is the only part I did not touch. I'll make a list with the problems.

Comment: i guess i have a problem with the .bib file because everything is ok when i use your mwe but when i pass to my .bib file and i complete compilation  bibtex i get this error message: "This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017)
The top-level auxiliary file: tesi.aux
I couldn't open database file library.lib.bib
---line 15 of file tesi.aux
 : \bibdata{library.lib
 :                     }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command"

Comment: @ggg You have to write `\bibliography{library}` (without ending) not `\bibliography{library.lib}`

Comment: yes i did it i change it. in the line 15 (mentioned in the error message there is just \usepackage{natbib}

Comment: @ggg Did you compile `(pdf)latex, bibtex, (pdf)latex, (pdf)latex ` after the change?

Comment: the error message above appear when i try to compile bibtex (after having correctly compile with latex)

Comment: @ggg Please show the .log file from running latex

Comment: do you mean the file with the same name of my .tex but with .log extension?

Comment: @ggg Yes. It might be to long to include in your question - in this case I suggest to use pastebin.com

Comment: @ggg If the error message from bibtex does not show the new file name without the .lib., I suspect that the latex run did not succeed.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mamuDnW7 is it what  you mean?

Comment: @ggg Do you have `\begin{document}` in `Results1.tex` (and all the other included files)?

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I fix it writing a new .lib file with just the entry i need. Probably the problem is somewhere in the .lib file which i gathered from Mendeley. (i delete the \begin{document} from every other file)

Comment: @ggg You should still solve the errors in your main file.

Comment: yes I solved all the issues you wrote in each comment!